# Spring Boot testing - stubbing method from difference reference of one class

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-boot, mockito

Using Spring Boot starter test to test my application. I am using third party library(`GRequest.class)` in my application and I want to stub one of his method.

Lets suppose we have a class `GRequest.class` and it has `send()` method and I want to stub that method in my junit test class by using `@MockBean GREquest` and `stub`

```
Mockito.when(grequest.send).willReturn(null) ;
```

Now I am calling the method which I want to test, in that method definition I am also creating GRequest object and calling send method.

```
GRequest request = new GRequest() ;
request.send() ;
```

Now I am unable to return the stub result. I believe as there are different reference of GRequest, it is not working. Can somebody have a look into it.

Comment: are you auto wiring GRequest to your class?

Comment: Obviously those are different. You are creating a new instance yourself, how should that be mocked? Use the injected, mocked instance instead.

Comment: @Jobin No, I am not auto wiring GRequest in my class.

Comment: @M.Deinum Actually I can't change that implemented class. I can only arrange my test class to test my implementation.

Comment: Then mocking won't work. I you cannot change the code that does `new GRequest` to use auto wiring it is pretty much a futile attempt.

Comment: @M.Deinum Can I use Mockito.when(any(GRequest.class).send()).willRertun(null) Something like that

Comment: No. As long as the code doesn't use the mocked instance and creating its own instance nothing will help. (Well you could probably use AOP to do some nasty stuff it you really wanted to but not sure if that would help your testing). Why would you want to mock the send method?

Comment: Have you tried with spies?

Comment: you can make it work by auto wiring GRequest to your application.